# How to properly use a ternary expression with @click event in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm showing a list of release versions, but the part I'm stuck on is I want to be able to click the release version and show the `job_execs` for that version. I'm not sure how to do this other than using a ternary expression and binding it to click event.  Anyway, what I'm trying to do is not working because nothing changes when I click the versions.

```
<template> 
  <td>
    <div v-for="release in release_versions" :key="release">
      <li>
        <span @click="showRelease = showRelease === release.version ? '' : release">
          Release {{ release.version }}
        </span>
        <ul v-if="showRelease === release.version">
          {{ release.job_execs }}
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </td>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LatestBuilds',
  data() {
    return {
      release_versions: [
        { version: '1', job_execs: [] },
        { version: '2', job_execs: [] },
      ],
      showRelease: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Important things to note:

- `job_execs` is populated with data, I'm just not showing it in the OP;
- the numbers of versions and `job_execs` are always changing;
- I'd rather not use a ternary expression if at all possible, just not 
  sure how else to do this.

Comment: are you sure you want a triple comparison operator? You initial value is `false` but you are comparing `booleans`, and `strings`.

Comment: I just want to click on a version and get the job executions for that version in the cleanest way possible

Comment: Also its better to keep computations out of markup. You can have a method call `@click="changeRelease(release)"`, pass in the parameter and change that data prop in the method.

Comment: You don't need a ternary operator here, just do `showRelease = release.version` and then it will work.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think his goal is to allow the user to toggle showing the release versions (an accordion).

Comment: If he wants to toggle an array would be better suited for this.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Did you mean another array to track the toggled item? He seems to be implementing an accordion (only one expanded item at a time), so that extra array wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: @tony19 I am talking about `showRelase`

Comment: I know what you meant. That link doesn't demo anything.

Comment: @benjaminadon Your code would've worked if your ternary used `release.version` in the  `false` case. See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-toggle-4p1qd)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use a [Method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Handling-User-Input) here, instead of adding this logic inside the `@click` attr.

To actually output the selected release's `job_execs`, you'll need another `v-for` inside the `ul`.

Something like the following should work:

```
<template> 
  <td>
    <div v-for="release in release_versions" :key="release">
      <li>
        <span @click="selectRelease(release.version)">
          Release {{ release.version }}
        </span>
        <ul v-if="selectedVersion === release.version">
          <li v-for="job_exec in release.job_execs">
            {{ job_exec }} <!-- use job_exec data if this is an object -->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </td>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LatestBuilds',
  data() {
    return {
      release_versions: [
        { version: '1', job_execs: [] },
        { version: '2', job_execs: [] },
      ],
      selectedVersion: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectRelease(version) {
      this.selectedVersion = version
    }
  },
}
</script>
```